# Why I can't apply margin for textView (android)?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

TextView code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/domain_text"
    tools:text="Description"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
```

[Here you can look at whole XML file](https://github.com/Maximsiomin/DomainsAPI/blob/main/activity_main)
Everything seems to be correct but if I launch the app I see that it doen't work. Look at the screenshot. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3C8t.png)

If you don't understand something, write about it, my english is quite poor. 
How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use constraints and want to set the `width`/`height` of the widget according to the set constraints, you set its `width`/`height` to `0dp` which means fill the contraints as:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

It will fill all the available space according to the Constraints and then, will your `margin` work.